# Looking for ideas of how to cut out part of a matrix and plant in another one

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code and where i get stuck:

```
mat=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
n=2
nxn=[0]*(n**2)
nxn=[[nxn[x:x+n] for x in range(0,len(nxn),n)]]

#[[0,0],[0,0]]

for row in range(n):
    for col in range(n):
10      nxn[row][col]= mat[row][col]

print(nxn)
```

It writes back: “index error: list index out of range”
—>10

## would like to get [[0,1],[5,6]]

Thanks a lot

Comment: 10 written just to mark row and doesn’t exist in original code

Comment: I'd suggest numpy if you want to work with matrices. If you convert it to a numpy array, you can do: ```mat[:2,:2]```.

Answer (score 2):

The following will get you all the `n` first element from the first `n` sub-lists in the main `mat` list

```
[l[:n] for l in mat[:n]]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1], [5, 6]]
```

If the `n` is larger then any of the list you will just get the whole list.

For example:

```
mat=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
n = 10
nxn = [l[:n] for l in mat[:n]]
print(nxn)
```

will results:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
```